# What is the best way to access things in a Form from another Form? C#

Tags: c#, forms

I was just wondering. If I have two forms.. Form 1 and Form 2 and you need to access a textbox, a label etc.. for example to make it visible or to change its text..

Which is the best way to access these from Form2?

Making a method in Form 1 like:

```
public void setTextBoxVisible(){
     textBox1.Visible = true;
}
```

or making an accessor in Form 1, and change the visibility from Form 2, like:

In Form 2:

```
public TextBox TextBox1 {
    get { return textBox1; }
}
```

In Form 1:

```
Form1 form1 = new Form1();
form1.TextBox1.Visible = true;
```

I know it may be a stupid question but I am still new to programming and I wish to know the best way I could do these things. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1 is definitely better, because you are only exposing the part that you want to expose.
Not only are you leaving less room for error on part of the caller, but you are stating the intent of your method.

In option 2, all aspects of your control are accessibly and can be changed from outside code, not only the `Visible` property.

You could, if it suits your preference better, create a property:

```
public bool TextBox1Visible
{
    get { return TextBox1.Visible; }
    set { TextBox1.Visible = value; }
}
```

Comment: Oh didn't know that was possible! Thanks a lot Rotem.. So this way you would only be exposing the visibility too!

Comment: +1, I was about to type a similar extension to my answer, just saw your :)

Comment: Exactly, and you are letting `Form1` be responsible for it's own UI, as is preferable.

Answer (score 2):

In your 2nd scenario you are declaring read-only property , whereas in First approach you are exposing the functionality through a `public` function, which IMO is more clear and  better approach.

EDIT:
One of the problem which I see with your first approach is that you can't stop a user from changing some property other than Visible. The user (developer) can mistakenly set the Text Property of your TextBox as well. e.g.

```
form1.TextBox1.Text = "Some new text";
```

The above is not a desired behaviour. *(You only wanted to set Visible property)*

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I thought that too but was not sure if it is recommended to have an accessor though!

Comment: You are welcome, One of the problem which I see with your first approach is that you can't stop a user from changing some property other than Visible.

Answer (score 2):

Programmers preference I think.. I always prefer method 1 as theres less room for error and if you want to change what it does in a lot of instances then its done in one line of code

Answer (score 0):

Use a datamodel as a seperated class. Use the observer / MVVM pattern to get notified when the datamodel gets changed.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have some action in Form2 that triggers the change to Form 1.  Given your options I would got for 1.  Another option is to consider events.  Form1 subscribes to an event on Form2.  When it gets triggered you can pass whatever you want to Form1 and have it carry out whatever updates or changes you want.